# Automated Data Entry Form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, data-entry

Trying to get help figuring out why my data form isn't linking properly to my database. I am very new at this and tried to follow a tutorial multiple times to get what I needed, but get all the way through and no matter what I tweak I am coming up with issues.

Here is what the form looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhqsU.png)

Connected to a 12 column excel database. Only 2 sheets in the workbook (Home and Database)
Keep getting the below error:

1. Run-time error '380' "Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value." There is supposed to be a mini preview of the form down in the "Database" area but its not showing up.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Reset()

    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] 'identifies the last row
    
    With frmForm
    
         .txtID.Value = " "
         .txtName.Value = " "
         .txtCostc.Value = " "
         .txtDept.Value = " "
         .txtPay.Value = " "
         .txtSdate.Value = " "
         .txtSuper.Value = " "
         .optCWS.Value = False
         .optFWS.Value = False
         
         .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 12
         .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
         
         .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30,60,75,40,60,45,55,60,60,60,60"
         
        If iRow > 1 Then
        
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:K" & iRow
        Else
        
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:K"
            
        End If
            
    
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Submit()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A] + 1

With sh

    .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1
    
    .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.txtID.Value
    
    .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtName.Value
    
    .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.txtSuper.Value
    
    .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.txtDept.Value
    
    .Cells(iRow, 6) = IIf(frmForm.optFWS.Value, "S09996", "S09992")
    
    .Cells(iRow, 7) = IIf(frmForm.optCWS.Value, "S09992", "S09996")
    
    .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.txtCostc.Value
    
    .Cells(iRow, 9) = frmForm.txtSdate.Value
    
    .Cells(iRow, 10) = frmForm.txtPay.Value
    
    .Cells(iRow, 11) = Application.UserName
    
    .Cells(iRow, 12) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYY HH:MM:SS")]
    
End With

End Sub

Sub Show_Form()

    frmForm.Show
    
End Sub
```

Debugger keeps taking me down to the **show form** portion:
[image]

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong with this?

Comment: Set your VBA error option to "Break in class module" and you'll see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA error is quite sophisticated itself, saying something about a `Rowsource Property`. In your code, the error should be here:

```
.lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:K"
```

obviously there is something missing after the `K`, for example:

```
.lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:K1"
```